# Database design with foreign key possibly being from different tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

I am trying to design a database for my application and I am struggling with something.

I need to store a Collection:

[image]

As you can see, the Collection has an ID and a date, easy so far.
(Please ignore the analysisID)

The problem is the target, which is a bit tricky. A Collection can have two different types of targets (let's say, a book or a magazine - mutually exclusive), both having IDs that could, eventually, coincide, as they are in two different tables. What would be a good approach for this?
I thought about creating two different foreign keys (one for book and the other for magazine), and one of them would always be NULL, which I think is far from the best approach.

Sorry if something was unclear, if you have any doubts, please just ask :)

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654071/db-design-to-use-sub-type-or-not/1654483#1654483

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A196713+subtype

Comment: Thanks Damir, it really helps! I hadn't considered subtyping, but I will give it a try!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems in your application `Book` entity and `Magazine` entity can take the same role, it is called target role.
It leads me to have a base table for book and magazine containing shared properties of them, like name, date-released, ... I am going to call the base table `Writing` table.
Writing table will have a one-to-one relationship to magazine and book (forigen key of 
writing will be the primary key of book and magazine).
Having the writing key in collection table (target-id) will solve the problem.

[image]